# Sort numerically in VI editor

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort numeric and literal columns in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355004/how-to-sort-numeric-and-literal-columns-in-vim)

I have to sort the below lines based on thread id.

```
Internal thread 0 bound to OS proc set {1}
Internal thread 1 bound to OS proc set {5}
Internal thread 2 bound to OS proc set {9}
Internal thread 10 bound to OS proc set {41}
Internal thread 9 bound to OS proc set {37}
```

When I issue `:!sort -n` they get sorted like this:

```
Internal thread 0 bound to OS proc set {1}
Internal thread 1 bound to OS proc set {5}
Internal thread 10 bound to OS proc set {41}
Internal thread 2 bound to OS proc set {9}
Internal thread 9 bound to OS proc set {37}
```

But I need them to be sorted like this:

```
Internal thread 0 bound to OS proc set {1}
Internal thread 1 bound to OS proc set {5}
Internal thread 2 bound to OS proc set {9}
Internal thread 9 bound to OS proc set {37}
Internal thread 10 bound to OS proc set {41}
```

Comment: In your case, done as `:%!sort -n -k 3`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks it works perfect. Please provide this as an answer so that I can accept it. I understand the options `n` and `3`. But what why do I need an extra `-k`. Is `n` not sufficient for numerical sort

Comment: `-k 3` explicitely sorts on the 3rd field.

Answer (score 81):

Just use Vim's own sort function. Visually highlight the text (or use a range) and type:

`:sort n`

Documentation is available here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Sort_lines

Or in Vim itself: `:help sort`

*(Edited to reflect an important point of clarification from dash-tom-bang and the reference to Vim's own help file.)*

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not the removal of the dash that's the big difference here, it's that it's using functionality that's built into Vim instead of calling an external application (note the lack of a `!` as well).  Documentation is also available in Vim itself; `:help :sort`

Comment: I've edited my answer because I think your point is important enough to make more prominent.