# Alphabetize lines of a given range in vim

Tags: vim, alphabetical

I have several lines that I want to alphabetize.  For example, say I have a bunch of vim `set` commands in a file:

```
set nowrap
set number
set expandtab
set hlsearch
set list
```

How would I alphabetize these 5 lines?  The output would look like this:

```
set expandtab
set hlsearch
set list
set nowrap
set number
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355004/how-to-sort-numeric-and-literal-columns-in-vim. eg set the sort column by excluding the first word and space 2,5 sort /^\S\+\s\+/ but in this case just :1,5 sort would work as the first column is the sane

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The vim `:sort` command takes in a command line range, and allows you to use a regex to select what is sorted.  You can also use the external sort command the same way, using `:{range}!sort` In my case, `:1,5sort` does what I want.  More help on the `:sort` command is available in this vim help topic:

`:help :sort`