# How to sort by date in a CSV log with Vim?

Tags: sorting, vim

Trying to sort a FreeSWITCH CDR (call detail records) file that looks like this,

```
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 16:52:37","2020-10-12 16:52:37","2020-10-12 16:52:42","5","5","NORMAL_CLEARING","5f26b500-d6b1-4c8a-b3ed-cfbea629f011","","","PCMU","PCMU"
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 18:01:37","2020-10-12 18:01:37","2020-10-12 18:02:24","47","47","NORMAL_CLEARING","7bc81c2b-e811-4e8e-adbc-286b24837c51","","","PCMU","PCMU"
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 18:11:51","2020-10-12 18:11:51","2020-10-12 18:12:51","60","60","NORMAL_CLEARING","3e735f44-05a9-4d49-8bc8-7588e32fa03a","","","PCMU","PCMU"
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 18:15:59","2020-10-12 18:15:59","2020-10-12 18:17:16","77","77","NORMAL_CLEARING","38746ac1-3915-489e-834b-f30753d5a9c7","","","PCMU","PCMU"
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 18:20:07","2020-10-12 18:20:08","2020-10-12 18:21:12","65","64","NORMAL_CLEARING","a104497d-ca59-434f-9b95-013496e42b4f","","","PCMU","PCMU"
"+19168897510","+19168897510","+19167324000","default","2020-10-12 18:22:40","2020-10-12 18:22:40","2020-10-12 18:23:39","59","59","NORMAL_CLEARING","6f6082a3-6b3c-44d6-9ec7-aed6dc5784f1","","","PCMU","PCMU"
```

and would like to sort it based on the first date-time column (e.g., `2020-10-12 16:52:37`).

What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355004/how-to-sort-numeric-and-literal-columns-in-vim) got me started, and the answer is:

```
:sort nr /\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}/
```

Relevant parts from `:h :sort`:

```
===============
7. Sorting text                     *sorting*

Vim has a sorting function and a sorting command.  The sorting function can be
found here: |sort()|, |uniq()|.

                            *:sor* *:sort*
:[range]sor[t][!] [b][f][i][n][o][r][u][x] [/{pattern}/]
            Sort lines in [range].  When no range is given all
            lines are sorted.

            [..]

            Options [n][f][x][o][b] are mutually exclusive.

            With [n] sorting is done on the first decimal number
            in the line (after or inside a {pattern} match).
            One leading '-' is included in the number.

            [..]
            
            With [r] sorting is done on the matching {pattern}
            instead of skipping past it as described above.
            For example, to sort on only the first three letters
            of each line: >
```

The regex to match the date-time format of `2020-10-12 16:52:37` (see also: [Unix Stackexchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90345/vim-search-numbers-containing-specific-number-of-digits)):

- `\d{N}` matches N number of digits (see `:h regex`, or `h /character-classes` and `h /\{` specifically)
- `-`,  , and `:` are matched literally

---

There is [a cool CSV Vim plugin/script](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_CSV_files), but it was an overkill in my case.